# PHP - PDO - MSSQL and Deleting with apostrophes

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have read all the posts I can about apostrophes and I'm still in the dark.  In this code I'm trying to delete a record that contains an apostrophe and a space.  I can't get it to delete. The code works fine unless there is an apostrophe.  I'm working in php/dbo working with an MSSql database.  I've deleted the password and username from the sample code.

```
    <?php 
    $attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
    $pdo = new PDO("dblib:host=Server;dbname=Aer;charset=utf8", "", "");
    $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $TestString="tom's tom";
    $TestString = str_replace("'", "''", $TestString) ;
    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM JNO_Clubs WHERE Club = :id');
        $stmt->bindValue(':id',$TestString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

I've tried with and without the line:

```
$TestString = str_replace("'", "''", $TestString) ;
```

If you can help I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to replace the apostrophe with the double apostrophes:

```
$TestString="tom's tom";
 $TestString = str_replace("'", "''", $TestString) ;
 try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM JNO_Clubs WHERE Club = :id');
    $stmt->bindValue(':id',$TestString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

because I'd wager that the call to bindValue will take care of that for you.  It's likely that the execution of that statement is passing "tom''''s tom" in as the value of :id.  Try removing the call to str_replace.